Damped track acts weird all of the sudden
Dear people i can't seem to find an answer so I'll ask it here.
I have a model I'm adjusting the rig off and I added bones for the hood and tail.
The hood worked perfectly fine with the damped track. Yet the tail here totally shifts direction each time I add the damped track to the bone.
does anyone know why this happens? Is it just a bug or did I do something wrong??





Never mind I'm an absolute dumb f*k.
In order to "fix" this problem I need to select them in the right order.
Starting from the end of the tail to the beginning and not the other way around.
I'm sucha Idiot.
